# eclipse does not resolve all includes

Tags: eclipse, avr

I am working on an avr project in eclipse and include files supplied by the compiler. Eclipse recognize the includes in code (i.e. no question mark by the #include) but it does not resolve the defines in the included files, i.e. PINA is not recognized as a memory address.

I've tried to add the include directory as a library path in Paths and Symbols. I've tried to add it as a library path to the build settings. Neither one worked.

I am using Eclipse Indigo and ImageCraft compiler. Furthermore, in the projects I've included imagecraft's include directory as a link (to enable search).

Any ideas?

Comment: I just upgraded to Indigo and OS X 10.7 and I am having similar problems.  I get Symbol <...> cannot be resolved on code that was working before. I have seen a few posts on avr-freaks, but have not found a solution yet. Cheers Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Project should be created as a standard C project. Under Project / Properties / C/C++ General / Paths and Symbols in the Includes tab. Choose Add... and point it to the library path (in my case: C:\icc7avr\include). That seems to solve it for most projects.

However I have a nested project (project is a subset of another project) where this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. The default already had this path (using / notation as path separators), and it was not sufficient. When I manually added the same folder again (now it was displayed in bold and using \ path separators, I'm on WinXP) and cleaned/rebuild a few times it picked it up correctly.